# Addepar Ember Table Example (Non Coffeescript)

Tags: ember.js, ember-table

Is there any place to see an example of how to use this without knowing coffeescript? I have tried to convert the examples to just plain JS and its throwing errors all over the place.

https://github.com/Addepar/ember-table

Edit:

I am trying to use this in conjunction with Django-REST to enable pagination and sorting of the column data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been working on combining [rCharts](http://rCharts.io) with Addepar's ember tables.  As a result, I have some very basic replications of the simple and bar example.  You can see them in the Readme.md in https://github.com/timelyportfolio/rCharts_addepar_ember.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Ember-Table now has a JS Bin example, currently http://emberjs.jsbin.com/feqih/1/edit. The project linked by timelyportfolio looks like a great example of a full project; this is just a simpler alternative for people who want to see at a glance how ember-table can be used in a javascript app.

Updated versions of the JS Bin will be linked from the main ember-table github page: https://github.com/Addepar/ember-table.

Comment: If someone could modify this example to show how one could do summing of all column values in the footer I would be eternally grateful. I'm new to Ember and Javascript programming and am still struggling with the Ember learning curve. Thanks in advance!